# Can you autoplay videos sound-on in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, autoplay

I'm working on a landing page and need to make a  element autoplay sound-on when the video is scrolled into view.

Browsers are pretty strict towards this (and understandably so, given it can ruin UX). Some workarounds that I came across are:

- Including video controls;
- Checking for user interaction (click, keypress etc.);
- Checking whether the user has been redirected from another page of the same domain.

The first is not an option, for visual considerations. The other two apparently work in Chrome/Firefox, but not on Safari, which blocks the video.

Is there any way to autoplay a video with sound in Safari?

Comment: in order to play a video with audio, the action should always be initiated by the user (click, keypress or such), and this is true for chrome and ff too, safari is not different in that sense

Comment: Websites all of a sudden starting to blare sound, just because I _scrolled_, is absolutely contrary to my expectations. If Chrome and Firefox allow you to do that without an explicit click anywhere, _just_ based on scrolling - then those two browsers are letting me down.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.